# SVN authz file not working when checkout on the same server

Tags: svn

When I create svn proj on a server, I modify authz and svnserve.conf to control the access of other users, but after I tried many times and found: On the same server, other user can use 'svn co file:///path/to/my/proj' to checkout the svn proj without passwd even I config all users have no authority to access my svn proj! Of cause, if other users on the same server using 'svn co svn://' checkout my proj, the passwd and authority are needed.

Have I missed something when using SVN? Thanks!

Comment: Don't use, and don't allow `file://` access. [Choosing a Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.choosing.html)

Comment: Thank you crashmstr, I have read that web and learned a lot, thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

If users have filesystem-level access to your repository database, they can check out via `file:///` and when using that protocol, there is no other authentication and no path-based authorization.

Even worse, if users have enough permission at the filesystem level, they can corrupt your entire repository by editing/moving/deleting files.

You need to lock down the **filesystem** permissions on the directory hosting your Subversion repositories such that only administrators and the `svnserve` process have permission to access it.

Comment: Thank you alroc, that helps me a lot!